# Is it possible to use HWI (Hive Web Interface) in single node installation?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Is it possible to use HWI (Hive Web Interface) in single node installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes!! As long as Hive server is running in your node, HWI can be accessed.

> http://localhost:9999/hwi